# I want to add a column of identical text values to the output of the FILTER function

Tags: arrays, excel, filter, dynamic, formula

I'm using VSTACK to combine the output of different filters (same structure, but from different worksheets). However, I want to be able to identify from which sheet each row has been filtered, so I was wondering if it is possible to add a column to each array to contain a certain identifier. Essentially this would be the same as using HSTACK for the filter output and a custom array with 1 column that has all the same values. Any ideas?

Comment: In every filter use `HSTACK(FILTER(...),EXPAND("SheetName",COUNTA(FILTER(...)),,"SheetName"))`

Comment: Or, if you ok with index numbers: `=EXPAND(FILTER(...),,2,SHEET(...))` and keep using `VSTACK()` for each seperate filter.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful already! Any way to get the identifier in the first column? It's quite a lot of columns, so not very handy if it's all the way to the right..

Comment: Not sure how many columns you got but if you finalized your `VSTACK()` parameters, just nest this whole function in a `=LET(x,VSTACK(.....),HSTACK(TAKE(x,,-1),DROP(x,,-1)))`.